# <input> multi-line capable via CSS

Tags: html, css, input, textarea

Is there a way to get an `<input />`-field in HTML to wrap lines if the text is longer than the field using CSS? I don't want to use `<textarea />` as I want to avoid users entering hard line-breaks by pressing enter.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

No, sorry.  `<input type=text>` is single line by definition.  See the W3C document [Forms in HTML Documents](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#input-control-types):

```
text
    Creates a single-line text input control.
```

Answer (score 3):

Using Dojo's Dijit TextArea form control, based off TextArea, you can have an input field which begins as a single line and expands as the user adds to it.

See [its documentation](http://docs.dojocampus.org/dijit/form/Textarea).

Answer (score 3):

You can't do what you want with CSS alone, but you could use JavaScript to prevent the user from entering line breaks in a `<textarea>` field.

Comment: He wants an input that wraps. That sounds like a textarea to me. He just didn't want the user to be able to enter line breaks, which you could do with JavaScript.

Answer (score 3):

Look at this, 
http://www.echoecho.com/htmlforms08.htm

> The wrap options are the most tricky part of text areas.
>   If you turn wrap off the text is handled as one long sequence of text without linebreaks.
>   If you set it to virtual the text appears on your page as if it recognized linebreaks - but when the form is submitted the linebreaks are turned off.
>   If you set it to physical the text is submitted exactly as it appears on the screen - linebreaks included.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is use a textarea (with autogrow capabilities if you like), and then strip out the new lines when the form is submitted. Using php it would be something like this:

```
$text = str_replace(array("\n","\r"),'',$_POST['text_field']);
```

This would have the desired effect of blocking newline characters. As others have pointed out it's not really possible to get multi-line input in an input field.